# indexError: list indexing error and wrongful tracking of counters

Tags: python, list

The goal of the program is to define a procedure that takes in a string of numbers from 1-9 and outputs a list with the following parameters:
Every number in the string should be inserted into the list.

If a number x in the string is less than or equal to the preceding number y, the number x should be inserted into a sublist. Continue adding the following numbers to the sublist until reaching a number z that is greater than the number y.

Then add this number z to the normal list and continue.

```py
#testcases
string = '543987'
numbers_in_lists(string)
result = [5,[4,3],9,[8,7]]
```

```py
def numbers_in_lists(string):
    # Convert the sequence of strings into an array of numbers
    i = 0
    conv_str_e = []
    while i < len(string):
        conv_str_e.append(int(string[i]))
        i += 1

    #official code starts here
    normal_list = []
    list_of_small_nums = [[]]

    # This will help me keep track of elements of the normal_list.
    previous_e_pos = -1
    e_pos = 0

    # this one will be used to decide if the element should go into the 
    #normal_list or list_of_small_nums
    check_point = 0


    for e in conv_str_e:

        #The first element and every elements bigger the element with 
        #check_point as it's index
        #will be put into the normal_list as long as the list inside 
        #list_of_small_nums is empty
        if e_pos == 0 or e > conv_str_e[check_point]:

            #If the list inside list_of_small_nums is not empty
            if list_of_small_nums[0] != []:

                #concatenate the normal_list and list_of_small_nums
                normal_list = normal_list + list_of_small_nums[0]

                #Clear the list inside list_of_small_nums
                list_of_small_nums[0] = []

            #Add the element in the normal_list
            normal_list.append(e)

            # Update my trackers
            e_pos += 1
            previous_e_pos += 1

            # (not sure this might be the error)
            check_point = e_pos

        #The curent element is not bigger then the element with the 
        #check_point as index position
        #Therefor it goes into the sublist.

        list_of_small_nums[0].append(e)
        e_pos += 1
        previous_e_pos += 1

    return list
```

Comment: Please provide what string is as well.

Comment: I gave it under Check under the test case exemple. string = '543987'

Comment: Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you were doing wrong was exactly what you pointed out in your comments. You just kept increasing `e_pos` and so `check_point` eventually was greater than the length of the list.

I took the liberty of changing some things to simplify the process. Simple programs make it easier to figure out what is going wrong with them. Make sure you always try to think about the simplest way first to solve your problem! Here, I replaced the need for `e_pos` and `previous_e_pos` by using `enumerate`:

```py
string = '543987'

# Convert the sequence of strings into an array of numbers
conv_str_e = [int(i) for i in string]

#official code starts here
normal_list = []
list_of_small_nums = []

# this one will be used to decide if the element should go into the 
#normal_list or list_of_small_nums
check_point = 0


for ind, e in enumerate(conv_str_e):

    #The first element and every elements bigger the element with 
    #check_point as it's index
    #will be put into the normal_list as long as the list inside 
    #list_of_small_nums is empty
    if ind == 0 or e > conv_str_e[check_point]:

        #If the list inside list_of_small_nums is not empty
        if list_of_small_nums != []:

            #concatenate the normal_list and list_of_small_nums
            normal_list.append(list_of_small_nums)

            #Clear the list inside list_of_small_nums
            list_of_small_nums = []

        #Add the element in the normal_list
        normal_list.append(e)

        # Update my trackers
        check_point = ind

    else:
        #The curent element is not bigger then the element with the 
        #check_point as index position
        #Therefore it goes into the sublist.
        list_of_small_nums.append(e)

# If there is anything left, add it to the list
if list_of_small_nums != []:
    normal_list.append(list_of_small_nums)

print(normal_list)
```

Result:

```
[5, [4, 3], 9, [8, 7]]
```

I am sure you can change it appropriately from here to put it back in your function.

Comment: Thank you very much. my first first experience with stack overflow is great because of you.

Comment: @pq_bd No problem. Please accept and upvote this answer then if you found it useful!